# Biasing analog MEMS microphone

Tags: bias, mems-microphone, vcc, audio-codec

I am using a analog type MEMS microphone.(SMA120).
Interface chip PCM2912 provi

[SMA100 data sheet](http://senodia.com/Uploads/Product/58ad3eac498b1.pdf)

[PCM2912**a** data sheet](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=pcm2912a&fileType=pdf)

[PCM2912 product page](http://www.ti.com/product/PCM2912) **not for new designs**

Could you kindly suggest me a proper circuity ? Why we need MBIAS in this case? 
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the datasheet for the SMA120? Do you have a datasheet for it? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Kindly go through here, http://senodia.com/Uploads/Product/58ad3eac498b1.pdf

Comment: What a messed up datasheet.  It calls the output pin "data out" as though it were digital, then specifies it as though it were analog.  At any rate, it has Vdd (power,) ground, and out.  Your MBIAS goes to Vdd, ground to ground, and out to your PCM 2912.

Comment: Unfortunately, MBIAS does not work with this microphone. As MBIAS is 0.75times of VCCA you see. Its only work when you connect VDD of microphone with POWER of pcm2912. For the noise issues, RC filter is necessary here ?

Comment: What voltage in Volts (not net name etc) were and are you using on the mic. Why do you say MBIAS is not suitable ?

Comment: Supplying information little by little by .... is not a good way of getting a good (or any useful) answer. So far, what you have said seems inconsistent. eg you say " ... Its only work when you connect VDD of microphone with POWER of pcm2912 ..." and below you say 1.5 to 3.6V Vdd on microphone.
But PCM2912 data sheet says: " ...  The voltage source to power the PCM2912A must be between 4.35 V and 5.25 V for proper operation ...". So you cannot be  connecting the microphone Vdd to PCM2912 Vdd. You say they MUST be connected together BUT do not say why you think this etc. ...

Comment: ...  You need to supply a complete circuit diagram of what you are **actually** doing (eg where does the microphone get its Vdd?) and explanation of what your real and expected problems are and why you think you need to do things that the data sheet and application notes do not show.

Comment: Might be a misunderstanding or I am not connecting microphone Vdd with PCM2912 power port. Partially, I was trying 2 microphone with different Vdd range !

Answer (score 1):

Excellentish [PCM2912 Application Note here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sbau132/sbau132.pdf)

From the [SMA100 datasheet](http://senodia.com/Uploads/Product/58ad3eac498b1.pdf) note that **Vdd absolute maximum is 4.0V**   !!!!

Normal **operating Vdd range** is 1.5 to 3.6V

IF the PCXM2912 is operated fom 3.6V or less then you can share Vdd/Vcc between the two ICs. IF PCM2912 Vcc is 5V you MUST NOT share Vdds.

AT 5V Vdd on the CODEC the Mbias voltage is 5 x 75% = 3.75V which is above the recommended max operating microphone Vdd of 3.6V.

The microphone can be operated from a voltage dropper (2 resistors) to ensure proper Vdd with a decoupling capacitor at the microphone Vin.

The microphone analog output must be AC coupled with a capacitor to the CODEC IC.
See circuit in [PCM2912 Application Note](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sbau132/sbau132.pdf) section 5.1 page 38.
C10 is the microphone input capacitor.

The microphone Vdd in that case is fed with a 1k series resistor with no decoupling capacitor at the microphone.  This may not suit your microphone.

They operate the microphone from Vbias - which, as above, would not be suitable if CODEC Vcc is 5V.

Comment: Meaningful, I kept Vdd wired from other part of cascaded circuit.

Comment: @Hasan That tells me almost nothing useful, alas. We need to know the DC voltage used for the microphone.

Comment: Normal operating voltage you mentioned already, 1.5 to 3.6V.